# Accidental 'sudo grub-install'

Tags: grub2

I accidentally executed:

```
sudo grub-install
```

Now I don't want to restart the PC, because I'm afraid it might not boot. How can I check everything is alright?

Comment: Since you did not specify a device, maybe it failed. Did it give any message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify any device, `grub-install` has installed grub on default partition /dev/sda.

You can try to can check if it is all ok if

```
sudo update-grub
```

will generate grub configuration file without errors and if you see in command results an entry for each OS (or different kernel version) that you have installed on your machine.

You can find more information typing on your terminal `man grub-install` or `info grub-install`.